# Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

On my fresh install of Pop!_OS 19.04 I tried executing `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade` and this error happened:
`Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.` What is causing this error?

This has never happened before and I'm not sure what would have caused it. I tried using `sudo apt autoremove` and this didn't help.

```
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://apt.pop-os.org/proprietary disco InRelease                                            
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu disco InRelease                                 
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main Sources [90.3 kB]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main i386 Packages [218 kB]
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/main amd64 Packages [259 kB]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe amd64 Packages [299 kB]
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates/universe i386 Packages [295 kB]
Fetched 1,444 kB in 4s (389 kB/s)                                               
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
```

```
$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
4 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Setting up cups-daemon (2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1) ...
Failed to restart cups.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
invoke-rc.d: initscript cups, action "restart" failed.
● cups.service - CUPS Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/cups.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Tue 2019-09-03 15:02:28 CDT; 1h 21min ago
     Docs: man:cupsd(8)
 Main PID: 816 (cupsd)
    Tasks: 1 (limit: 4489)
   Memory: 4.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/cups.service
           └─816 /usr/sbin/cupsd -l

Sep 03 15:02:28 pop-os systemd[1]: Started CUPS Scheduler.
dpkg: error processing package cups-daemon (--configure):
 installed cups-daemon package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up uuid-runtime (2.33.1-0.1ubuntu3) ...
Failed to restart uuidd.service: Unit -.mount is masked.
invoke-rc.d: initscript uuidd, action "restart" failed.
● uuidd.service - Daemon for generating UUIDs
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/uuidd.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
     Docs: man:uuidd(8)
dpkg: error processing package uuid-runtime (--configure):
 installed uuid-runtime package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups-core-drivers:
 cups-core-drivers depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups-core-drivers (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of cups:
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                           cups depends on cups-core-drivers (>= 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package cups-core-drivers is not configured yet.
 cups depends on cups-daemon (>= 2.2.10-4ubuntu2.1); however:
  Package cups-daemon is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package cups (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Errors were encountered while processing:
 cups-daemon
 uuid-runtime
 cups-core-drivers
 cups
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

I am wondering what is causing these errors:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit -.mount is masked.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Take a look at this question: [Is unmask-ing root (“-.mount”) a unreasonable on Ubuntu 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1175385/62638).  I have put a few command examples for ways to troubleshoot this problem.  _But_ the implication of what I've found is not comforting.  I am looking for a more safe and reliable response.

Comment: I fixed this issue by restarting a daemon. I'm currently looking in to which one specifically. A reboot was a quick fix as well.